# Git program execution

Tags: java

I just cloned my git repo in a linux server.

```
The project is inside de directory /home/ea0
    root@eetacea0:/home/ea0# ls
    Dump20170604photos.sql  EetakemonGoCBL
```

And I want to execute the following file to run the application (which is the server for the web and mobile app)

```
root@eetacea0:/home/ea0/EetakemonGoCBL/src/main/java/Main# ls
App.java
```

How can I start running the program?

Comment: How are `git` or `github` involved in this question?

Comment: The project is in github but i clone it in my linux server with git clone

Comment: are you asking how to compile and run a Java program? Because that is not related to git. It is likely to be project specific.

Comment: Yes I just want to run my java program which I've just cloned with git

Answer (score 0):

First : compile your program with

```
javac App.java
```

Then run the `class` file created

```
java App
```

Of course you need Java installed on your computer